# validate access token with user name in Oauth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication for my SPA application. am facing one issue, For example there is two users, user1 and user2 both are logged in . when the user1 trying to use user2 ***access token***, user1 can access . i don't know how to secure access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out the solution. 
To customizing the access token we can secure the users access token. 
i have customize the access token using **Token enhancer**. 
Code will be like below

```
@Primary
    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

and custom enhancer will be like

```
 public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    AppUserDetails appUserDetails = (AppUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
    String encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(appUserDetails.getIdUser().toString().getBytes());
    additionalInfo.put("authorities", appUserDetails.getAuthorities());
    additionalInfo.put("username", appUserDetails.getUsername());
    additionalInfo.put("idUser", encodedBytes);
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
    return accessToken;
}
```

in other method i have decode the customize access token.
Also i have used AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer

```
@Override
    //Configure the properties and enhanced functionality of the Authorization Server endpoints.
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time when a user logged in using oauth2 authentication, it associates the user-id of the newly logged in user with an unique access_token, you can get that user_id, and in turn map it with the user_id of current logged in user to find out if its the user is using his own access_token.